# Login to Bank using VBA

Tags: vba, browser-automation

I am hoping to complete 2 simple tasks.  Input the password, and submit username and password to https://ktt.key.com

I am currently able to display my name in the username tab, but am having trouble entering password.  Please provide way to submit too.  Thanks for the help guys.

This is what I have so far...

```
Sub login()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object
  Dim objCollection As Object


  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://ktt.key.com/ktt/cmd/logon"

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
   Set htmlColl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("moduleTarget")

  With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("userId").Value = "xxxxx"
  HTMLDoc.getElementByName("moduleTarget").Value = "xxxxxx"
  End With




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you have objCollection set as an Object, so I will be using that one to populate your password field.

Change:

```
With HTMLDoc
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("userId").Value = "xxxxx"
    HTMLDoc.getElementByName("moduleTarget").Value = "xxxxxx"
End With
```

To:

```
With HTMLDoc
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("userId").Value = "xxxxx"
End With
```

And then under that, paste:

```
Set objCollection = HTMLDoc.getelementsbyname("txtPassword")
objCollection(0).Value = "1234" 'This is your password
```

So what this does it, it set a new object to the txtPassword Element collection.  Then it takes the first index (there's only one index here under "txtPassword") and assigns the value of your choice.  The full code (from `With HTMLDoc` down) should look like this:

```
With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("userId").Value = "xxxxx"
End With

Set objCollection = HTMLDoc.getelementsbyname("txtPassword")
objCollection(0).Value = "1234" 'This is your password
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm a try again, I totally did try that prior however.  Thats why I moved on to moduleTarget.  Thinking maybe the actual input spot was hidden in possibly moduleTarget for some reason.

Comment: The error I get when I try this is "Run-time error '462:  The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"

Comment: One thing i notice too, for "txtPassword" there is no adjoining "value=" like in "txtUserID", I think trying to set the value is where the error is, thats what made me think moduleTarget

Comment: I have a solution, I am updating my original answer now.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try in about 2 hours, have to plug away until lunch.  I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, it worked for me on that exact site so hopefully it does for you.  Update me with the results when you return.

Comment: It absolutely worked.  Thanks a ton.  Just learned quite a bit to about getting elements.

Comment: just as a side question, is "objCollection" set up like an array because "objCollection(0)" gives me that impression.

Comment: Glad to hear, learn and keep on learning.  Mark the answer as correct so others can see it :)

Yes, it's similar to an array.  It's an object which stores multiple indexes.  The indexes are stored by using the `GetElementsByName` function.  Since it can return multiple Elements (in this case it doesn't). It returns them as indexes.